# How do I remove a building in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

How can I get rid of a building I no longer want?  For example, if I wall myself in as Protoss and later need to get a probe out to expand.

Comment: As a side note, protoss walls are generally done with a zealot filling the gap to avoid destroying your own buildings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Destroy it. Unless it is a Terran bunker (which you can salvage) your only recourse is to destroy the building.

Edit: And by 'destroy' I mean to forcefully attack it with your own offensive units or workers.

Comment: I wish SC1 and SC2 can delete a building like Age of Empires does.

Comment: You should expand on this answer slightly. By destroy, you mean by issuing an attack order, correct?

Comment: Note that in the case of Terrans, bunkers can be salvaged, which allows you to get some (all?) of the minerals back that were originally spent on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push A for attack, and then left click the building.

Comment: It's left click, not right.

Comment: Rotsor wins a medal!

Answer (score 1):

You can only destroy structures/units that you no longer want, you can always feed your enemy said units as well. To destroy buildings/units yourself you have to select structures or units that are able to attack then press the "A" key to issue a force attack order. If you hold down shift you only have to press the "A" key once and you can select all the structures/units you want to destroy.

Destroy in this context means to issue an attack order from your structures/units that are able to deal damage against units/structures you no longer need. Keep in mind you can salvage a Terran Bunker, the only structure you can get a refund from after it is built.