# How do I sell back a completed building in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a building in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/how-do-i-remove-a-building-in-starcraft-2)

How do I sell back a completed building I don't need in the StarCraft 2 campaign?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a building in StarCraft 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/how-do-i-remove-a-building-in-starcraft-2) they are similar questions with identical answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the exception of the Bunker, you can't.

The Bunker has a salvage (<kbd>v</kbd> by default) command; you must empty it of troops first.